# Tokenize math expression - error undefined procedure

Tags: prolog

I am trying to tokenize math expression from user's input. I have written this code, but I don't understand, why the predicate "tokenize" isn't defined. I looked up to the definition, but I still don't see the problem.

```
input_infix:-
    write('Enter equation: '),
    readln(Input),
    tokenize(Input,Chars),
    writeln(Chars).

ERROR: Undefined procedure: tokenize/2
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] tokenize(['(',1|...],_1236)
ERROR:    [8] input_infix at d:/dokumenty/prolog/notation.pl:4
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Comment: `I looked up to the definition` Where did you look up the definition? Also how much experience do you have programming? I ask because `Undefined procedure` is something that most programmers who have programmed for a few months can understand and fix.

Comment: Of interest: [Interpreter](https://www.metalevel.at/alzint/alzint.pl) for AL(Z) programs by Markus Triska

Comment: Undefined means.... undefined. :) `tokenize/2` isn't part of SWI Prolog. It's an [add-on](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=tokenize) that SWI supports. Did you load it in as an add-on?